# What metal song is used in this trailer for the animated movie *The Secret Life of Pets*?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack, metal

I saw this in the trailers before *The Peanuts Movie*, it cracked me up.  Just wondering if it's a "real" song or if it was written for the movie (I can't see it ending up on a soundtrack for a kids movie...).

> [The Secret Life Of Pets - Official Teaser Trailer (HD) - Illumination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-80SGWfEjM)

The clip in question starts around [2:17](https://youtu.be/i-80SGWfEjM?t=137).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As user1556814 mentioned, this is a Song from System of A down, but on another album.

It is Track Number 7 of the Album 'Toxicity', called Bounce.

Could not find a studio version on youtube, but you can find some live versions:

[Bounce - System of A down](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7NLRY0f7el4)

the part used in your video starts around 0:22

*I remembered it, because it is the track right after their famous Song Chop Suey, which i heard a lot 10 years ago*

Answer (score 5):

I don't have time to verify, but I think the band is 'System of a Down'. Look at their main titles to check it out, especially in album 'Mezmerize' if my guess is correct:

> [System Of A Down - Mezmerize (Full Album)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ntc6Dw4Ikk0)

Don't be fooled by the start of a song, because their songs are usually fluctuating, so the passage is probably hidden!